# Как реализовать такие уголки для glyphicon / font awesome icons?

Tags: css, bootstrap, border, fontawesome

[image: Иконка fontawesome[1]]

```
 <div class="wrap-icon">
  <div class="wrap-inner">
   <i class="fa fa-plane fa-3x"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: А где вы взяли этот пример? Если на сайте каком-то, можно прям там в CSS  посмотреть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, не знаю, может можно проще, но я обычно такие вещи делаю примерно так:

```css
.wrap-inner{
  position: relative;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  color:red;
  transition: all 300ms;
}
.wrap-inner:hover{
  color:green;
}
.corner{
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-width: 3px;
}
.top{
  top: 0;
  border-top-style: solid;
}
.left{
  left: 0;
  border-left-style: solid;
}
.bottom{
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}
.right{
  right: 0;
  border-right-style: solid;
}
.top.left{
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
.top.right{
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.bottom.right{
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
}
.bottom.left{
  border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrap-icon">
  <div class="wrap-inner">
   <i class="fa fa-plane fa-3x"></i>
    <div class="corner top left"></div>
    <div class="corner top right"></div>
    <div class="corner bottom right"></div>
    <div class="corner bottom left"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно поиграться SVG :

```css
.orange {
  color: orange
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrap-icon">
  <div class="wrap-inner">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="50px">
      <path d="M25,2 L2,2 L2,25" fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-width="3" />
      <path d="M2,75 L2,98 L25,98" fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-width="3" />
      <path d="M75,98 L98,98 L98,75" fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-width="3" />
      <path d="M98,25 L98,2 L75,2" fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-width="3" />
      <foreignobject x="25" y="25">
        <i class="fa fa-plane fa-3x orange"></i>
      </foreignobject>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Пример взял [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33106451/2003555)

Comment: Лучший вариант реализации :) Только подравняйте пример

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот ещё, как вариант. Но к использованию не рекомендуется, так как является костылём :)

```css
.wrap-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  transition: all 300ms;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.wrap-inner:before {
  display:block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}
.wrap-inner:after {
  display:block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: -3px;
  width: 40px;
  height: calc(100% + 6px);
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrap-inner:hover {
  color: green;
}
.fa {position: relative; z-index: 2}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrap-icon">
  <div class="wrap-inner">
    <i class="fa fa-plane fa-3x"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```